# Remove last string from every line in file

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a txt file that I want to use sed, awk, grep or any combination to remove the last string of every line in a file.

I think I need something like sed '$s/'. But cant quite figure it out. Thanks.

Example:

```
fab foo bar

fab foo fab

fab foo foo
```

Desired output.

```
fab foo

fab foo

fab foo
```

Note that the last string will be different in every line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
awk '{$NF=""}1' file
```

Comment: +1, but note that this will modify whitespace as well

Comment: I like this answer for its simplicity, as most of the answers work. Unfortunately i didn't realize some lines actually have more than one string i want to delete. But will reference this post when the time comes. Thanks.

Comment: This will do more than just remove the last string on the line, itll recompile the whole record and add a trailing space.

Comment: it removed everything in my file!!! (in my file words in each line were separated with ",")

Comment: set separator, like `awk -F',' '{$NF=""}1' file`

Answer (score 4):

```
sed -r 's/[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]*$//' file
```

The above removes the last string of non-spaces on every line along with any white space before or after that string.

Comment: +1: Aah good thinking on removing the residual space before the last field.

Answer (score 4):

`awk '{if(NF)NF--}1' file`

The condition is needed as NF can't be assigned a negative value and blank lines already have `NF == 0`. If no blank lines in the input then `awk 'NF--' file` is enough

Answer (score 2):

You could try the below sed command,

```
sed 's/ \+[^ ]\+$//' file
```

Through perl,

```
perl -pe 's/\S+\s*$//' file
```

To remove also the leading spaces before the last word.

```
perl -pe 's/\s+\S+\s*$//' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to print every field except for the last:

```
awk '
{
   for(i=1; i<NF; i++) 
   {
      printf "%s ", $i;
   }
   printf "\n";
}'  file
```